# is there a function $\mu(x)$ where $\mu(x)+1=\mu(x^2)$ and almost differentiable everywhere

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

is there a function $\mu(x)$ where $\mu(x)+1=\mu(x^2)$ the is almost differentiable everywhere besides the poles which lie on The Julia set defined by $x^2+1$

$$\mu(-i)=-1,\mu(i)=-1,\mu(0)=0,\mu(1)=1,\mu(2)=2,\mu(5)=3,\mu(26)=4,\mu(677)=5$$

My hope is because all of the poles are disconnected from each other It could exist.

Comment: $\mu(x) + 1 = \mu(x)$!?

Comment: sorry wrote it wrong